# How to import a specific version of a class declared in a package in several locations?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to import

> org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

However, this class is already being declared in "AWS SDK for Java".
But I have also added the jar file commons-codec-1.8.jar and I want it to load it from there instead. If I use the eclipse interface, showing the possible import options I only get **org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64** so I don't really know how to force it to load it from the one in my referenced libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse build a big classpath that contains both jars but the Java runtime will load the 
first class it finds.

The AWS SDK uses apache commons codec as a dependency.
If you look at the [pom.xml](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/pom.xml) you can see they reference 1.3.

You can either change the pom, or if you don't use maven at all (downloaded the jars from AWS) remove the 1.3 jar from the 3rd party libraries and use only the new one.

Other option is to use 1.3 yourself and drop 1.8 from the classpath.
With standard classloaders it is not possible to load different versions of the same class name.

Comment: I see both of the jars now, i will try deleting the old one and revert to using that one if something in aws is broken. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As this both the jar following same structure it will pick one of them. for that you remove one the  .class file which you dont want and import it .

Comment: The problem is, I want to use the one that is not included by default in one of the SDKs I am using. So I can't do that. Plus who knows what that framework is using that class for, i might break it if i do it.